# Vue Cli 3 how to use the official PWA plugin ( Service Worker )

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, vue-cli, progressive-web-apps

on my first vue project attempting to wrestle with the official PWA plugin  ( https://github.com/yyx990803/register-service-worker ).
My specific problem: capturing the registered service worker and using it for anything. The github readme shows the exact file that is produced, and there seems to be zero documentation about how to work with this service worker once it is instantiated ( do I capture the registration instance? if so, how? )

I found this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1481 
and am providing a better place to talk about this, as I haven't been able to find any example code or clear documentation about how to work with this.

If anyone has some sample code, please share. Vue and the new cli are incredible tools, documenting things like this is a necessary step forward to increasing the adoption of the platform

Comment: the alternative a few people seem to have reached is to just simply not use this plugin and the boilerplate it provides, and instead create their own service worker following whatever documentation they can find online. That's a viable solution but I figured I'd give this the weekend to see if this plugin can be practically used

Comment: I think this might be more of a gap in your knowledge of service workers, than really a `vue` related issue.

Comment: very possible.. excellent observation

Comment: I used to have the same issue with the vue-cli 3 PWA plugin. The docs are less than ideal, you're right. I tried to answer your question with all the knowledge I gained while dealing with this problem. I hope it helps you.

Comment: yes @LandryBETE this is exactly what I was hoping for. I had saved this tab when I saw your reply back in september and am just opening it up now ( luckily my work project didnt require me to go any deeper into developing the PWA functionality until now ). Thank you so much for providing such a rich, in deptch response that im sure is going to help countless people

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As already pointed out, it's more of a "service workers" issue than a "vue cli" one.
First of all, to make sure we're on the same page, here's what the boilerplate content of *registerServiceWorker.js* should look like (vue cli 3, official pwa plugin):

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n'
      )
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updated () {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

If you haven't changed the BASE_URL variable in your .env file, then it should correspond to  the root of your vue app. You have to create a file named *service-worker.js* in the *public* folder (so that it's copied into your output directory on build).

Now, it is important to understand that all the code in the *registerServiceWorker.js* file does is register a service worker and provide a few hooks into its [lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#the_service_worker_life_cycle). Those are typically used for debugging purposes and not to actually program the service worker. You can understand it by noticing that the *registerServiceWorker.js* file will be bundled into the *app.js* file and run in the main thread.

The vue-cli 3 official PWA plugin is based on Google's workbox, so to use the service worker, you'll have to first create a file named vue.config.js at the root of your project and copy the following code in it:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...other vue-cli plugin options...
    pwa: {
        // configure the workbox plugin
        workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
        workboxOptions: {
            // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
            swSrc: 'public/service-worker.js',
            // ...other Workbox options...
        }
    }
}
```

If you already have created a vue.config.js file, then you just have to add the pwa attribute to the config object. Those settings will allow you to create your custom service worker located at `public/service-worker.js` and have workbox inject some code in it: the precache manifest. It's a .js file where a list of references to your compiled static assets is stored in a variable typically named `self.__precacheManifest`. You have to build your app in production mode in order to make sure that this is the case.

As it is generated automatically by workbox when you build in production mode, the precache manifest is very important for caching your Vue app shell because static assets are usually broken down into chunks at compile time and it would be very tedious for you to reference those chunks in the service worker each time you (re)build the app.

To precache the static assets, you can put this code at the beginning of your `service-worker.js` file (you can also use a try/catch statement):

```
if (workbox) {
    console.log(`Workbox is loaded`);

    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest);

} 
else {
    console.log(`Workbox didn't load`);
}
```

You can then continue programming your service worker normally in the same file, either by using the [basic service worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Custom_responses_to_requests) or by using [workbox's API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing). Of course, don't hesitate to combine the two methods.

I hope it helps !

Comment: The default `workboxPluginMode` for the PWA plugin is `GenerateSW`, so you don't actually need to create a SW file in your public dir, as the workbox does that for you. It's also important to understand that while indeed _registerServiceWorker.js` file does just register a service worker, the PWA plugin of `vue-cli` does actually also (again, by default) create a SW for you that (when built for production) by default caches your whole app for offline use successfully.

Comment: Nice. The `vue.config.js` did the trick and now it runs fine. Just one question though: Why do we need that extra `vue.config.js` file, isn't it already being loaded in the "register()"? Like... The boilerplate didn't make that extra file, but why?

Answer (score 48):

as an addition to the answer above: I wrote a small guide on how to go further and add some functionality to the custom service-worker, using the setup above. You can find it [here](https://medium.com/@kobededecker/vue-pwa-example-298a8ea953c9).

Four main things to keep in mind:

1. configure Workbox in `vue.config.js` to `InjectManifest` mode, pointing the `swSrc` key to a custom service-worker file in `/src`
2. In this custom service-worker, some lines will be added automatically in the Build process for importing the `precache-manifest` and `workbox CDN`. Following lines need to be added in the custom `service-worker.js` file to actually precache the manifest files:

   ```
   self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
   workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
   workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
   ```
3. Listen to registration events in the `registerServiceWorker.js` file. You can use the registration object that is passed as first argument to the event handlers to post messages to the `service-worker.js` file:

   ```
   ...
   updated(registration) {
     console.log("New content is available; please refresh.");
     let worker = registration.waiting
     worker.postMessage({action: 'skipWaiting'})
   },
   ...
   ```
4. Subscribe to messages in the `service-worker.js` file and act accordingly:

   ```
   self.addEventListener("message", (e)=>{
       if (e.data.action=='skipWaiting') self.skipWaiting()
   })
   ```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Very helpful, and nice article! It worked great for me. Maybe cli-plugin-pwa will soon add these extra features (user prompt, skipWaiting, etc) as part of the simpler GenerateSW. Until then, this is just what I needed.

Comment: +1000 I've looked everywhere for the complete picture but this is the only place I found it.  Google development guides give the full picture if you're writing your own Service Worker, but by default the Vue PWA plugin builds it for you. Vue PWA plugin docs weren't very helpful.  The register-service-worker npm module only really gives you basic hooks, but doesn't listen for messages by default. So this is super helpful since it ties them all together.

Comment: If using `generateSW` mode with workbox version v4.1.0 or higher, `self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});` already exists in generated `service-worker.js`